# Why does TfidVectorizer.fit_transform() change the number of samples and labels for my text data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have a data set that contains 3 columns for 310 data. The columns are all text. One column is text input by a user into an inquiry form and the second column are the labels (one of six labels) that say which inquiry category the input falls into.

```
>>> data.shape
(310 x 3)
```

I am doing the following preprocessing to my data before I run it through the `KMeans` algorithm from `sklearn.cluster`

```
v = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorized = v.fit_transform(data)
```

Now,

```
>>> vectorized.shape
(3,4)
```

From where I'm looking I seem to have lost data. I no longer have my 310 samples. I believe the shape of vectorized refers to `[n_samples, n_features]`.

Why does the value of samples and features change? I would expect the number of samples to be 310 and the number of features to be 6 (the unique number of groupings for my labeled data.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example with sample data?  As described in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform), you are supposed to call `.fit_transform` on an iterable of raw documents, not some sort of table.  You should only call `fit_transform` on your X data, not the labels you're trying to predict.

Comment: you had mentioned about only 2 columns, what about the third one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TfidfVectorizer()` cannot be applied on three columns at a time.

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform):

> **fit_transform**(self, raw_documents, y=None)
>
> Learn vocabulary and idf, return term-document matrix.
>
> This is equivalent to fit followed by transform, but more efficiently
>   implemented.
>
> **Parameters:**       raw_documents : iterable
>   an iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects
>
> **Returns:**     X : sparse matrix, [n_samples, n_features]
>   Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.

Hence, when apply on single column of text data only. In your code, it had just iterated through the column names and create a transform for it.

An example to understand, what is happening:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['this is first sentence','this one is the second sentence'],
                    'col2':['this is first sentence','this one is the second sentence'],
                    'col3':['this is first sentence','this one is the second sentence'] })
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
vec.fit_transform(data).todense()

# 
# matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 1., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 1.]])

vec.get_feature_names()

# ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

Now, the solution is that you have to join all the three column into one single column or 
apply vectorizer separately on each column and then append them at the end.

## Approach 1

```
data.loc[:,'full_text'] = data.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(data['full_text']).todense()
print(X.shape)
# (2, 7)

print(vec.get_feature_names())
# ['first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'this']
```

## Approach 2

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
import numpy as np

vec={}
X = []
for col in data[['col1','col2','col3']]:
    vec[col]= TfidfVectorizer()
    X = np.append(X, 
                  vec[col].fit_transform(data[col]))

stacked_X = hstack(X).todense()
stacked_X.shape
# (2, 21)

for col, v in vec.items():
    print(col)
    print(v.get_feature_names())

# col1
# ['first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'this']
# col2
# ['first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'this']
# col3
# ['first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'this']
```